# GET table of contents from a PDF with python

Tags: python, pdf, text, nlp, pymupdf

I'm trying to get Table of Contents from a PDF. I'm using PyMuPDF for that purpose. But it only extracts ToC if the PDF consists of Bookmarks. Otherwise it only results in an empty list.

```
def get_Table_Of_Contents(doc):
    toc = doc.getToC()
    return toc
toc= get_Table_Of_Contents(file)
toc
```

Comment: I am also facing same scenario. Did you find any approach which extracts ToC if the PDF doesn't consists of Bookmarks

Answer (score -1):

Convert pdf to html using pdf-html converter. You can parse html toextract whatever data you want using parser like beautifulsoup.

Answer (score -1):

Usually TOC is represented like a regular text on a page.

Try [pdfreader](https://pypi.org/project/pdfreader/) to extract texts and/or PDF "markdown".

Here is a sample code extracting all the above from a page:

```
from pdfreader import SimplePDFViewer, PageDoesNotExist

fd = open(your_pdf_file_name, "rb")
viewer = SimplePDFViewer(fd)

# navigate to TOC
viewer.navigate(toc_page_number)

viewer.render()
pdf_markdown = viewer.canvas.text_content
plain_text = "".join(viewer.canvas.strings)
```

then you can parse `plain_text` or `pdf_markdown` as regular strings.